# invoke intents by an event name in V2 with followupEventInput

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I try to migrate a V1 application to the new API V2 and I having issues with the followupEvent feature.

This is my use case :

- The user want to switch on the light in a specific room -> I have an
  intent "light_on" with the parameter "zone".
- If the name does not correspond to a known room, the webhook response
  contains a followupEvent to invoke the intent "unknown_zone".
- This intent tell to the user "Sorry I don't know the named zone
  '#unknown_zone.zone'. Can you repeat the name of the zone?". The user
  has then 3 tries to give a valid name.

To do so, in V1, my webhook response was:

```
{
      "contextOut":[{
          "name":"zone",
          "lifespan":3
       }],
      "followupEvent":{
          "name":"unknown_zone",
          "data":{
              "context_lifespan":"3",
              "current_action":"light_on",
              "zone":"garage"
            }
        }
    }
```

In V2, I tried to send the following response :

```
{
  "outputContexts": [{
    "name": "zone",
    "lifespanCount": 3
  }],
  "followupEventInput": {
    "name": "unknown_zone",
    "parameters": {
      "zone": "garage",
      "current_action": "light_on",
      "context_lifespan": "3"
    },
    "languageCode":"en-US"
  }
}
```

The intent "unknown_zone" is never invoked. I only receive the default response of my "light_on" intent.

I searched in documentation : [WebhookResponse](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/WebhookResponse), [EventInput](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/EventInput) but nothing helped me.
I also found this topic [v2-followupevent-from-webhook-upgrade-from-v1](https://discuss.api.ai/t/v2-followupevent-from-webhook-upgrade-from-v1/13725) but without success.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out why my response did not work. I did not follow the new V2 [format](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/Context) for output context name.

Format: projects/{Project ID}/agent/sessions/{Session ID}/contexts/{my_context_name}

The intent was never match because the context was not set properly.

Comment: The link you provided is broken now. Which is the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

The name property in the followupEventInput object refers to an event defined in an intent, not to the intent itself. You have to add the event "unknown_zone" in your intent's event section as shown in
[this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB5ap.png).

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I've done. The same response in V1 works perfectly.